# How to find the bottom position of the ScrollView for Android in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

How to find the ScrollView bottom position value in React Native for android. My requirement is while loading the page, scroll position have to show in bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way : it'll give you the height of the `ScrollView`.

```
onContentSizeChange = (width, height) => {
  console.log('scrollview width : ' + width);
  console.log('scrollview height : ' + height);
};

render () {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{height: Dimensions.get('window').height, backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD'}} onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}>
      {_.map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], (number) => {
        return <Text key={number} style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 30, paddingBottom: 30, backgroundColor: number % 2 ? 'red' : 'blue'}}>{number}</Text>;
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/EUyrTw).